# can not play mp3 with bit-rate more than 300kbps in visual basic 6.0 using MS multimedia control 6.0

Tags: vb6, mp3

well let me more clear about this problem-
I am giving a try to make a mp3 player in VB6.0
90% job is done cause it plays wave files,mp3(with bit rate less than 300kbps).
I don't know how to make it play high bit rate files.
Is there any way to make it a complete mp3 player?

Comment: and why the VS 2010 tag in the question?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in your files? Googling around I haven't found anyone with this problem, and it should have been quite common considering how many 320kbps files there are around. Are you sure your files aren't VBR (Variable Bit Rate)? Perhaps it supported only CBR file (Constant Bit Rate).

Comment: Yes I am sure those files arn't VBR.

Comment: @Davide Piras : I thought VS2010 coders must have mastered older versions.

Comment: @Pointer in the same way drivers of cars have mastered the use of horses :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get the media control to work (I tried writing a media player ~15 years ago too) you could try the Windows Media player controls (but seems a bit silly just wrapping another media player) or change away from VB6 and use Quartz/DirectShow directly.

Answer (score 0):

A bit rate 300kbps is very high for mp3 which is high quality audio play only, for higher than that use a video codec and deselect video output if audio is what you intend. Maybe it is the executing speed of the processor on your device is a little slow for high speed playback.

Comment: 320kbps files are quite common. They are considered to be nearly indistinguishable from the original. Unless he is using a pentium 66mhz, he shouldn't have any problem for speed :-)

Comment: I am using core i3 with 2.53GHz,most of my mp3 files are 320kbps,but some are of low quality.Have you guys tried that MS Multimedia control 6.0?

Comment: @Pointer Let's say this... There aren't many persons that still use VB6.0 and OCX. They are quite "old technology". VB6 is from 1998 (Wiki). It's 13 years ago? MS changed EVERYTHING with VB.NET .